# Retrofit android not working and has no error

Tags: java, android, rest, retrofit

I just implemented the retrofit android library for rest api call but it is not working and has no  error. My code is

ApiInterface.java

```
public interface ApiInterface {
    @POST("url")
    void getLoginResponse(@Field("username") String username , @Field("password") String password,
                          @Field("clientId") String clientId , Callback<LoginResponse> cb);
}
```

RestClient.java

```
public class RestClient {

    private static ApiInterface REST_CLIENT;
    private static String BASE_URL = "base_url";
    static {
        setupRestClient();
    }

    private RestClient() {}

    public static ApiInterface get() {
        return REST_CLIENT;
    }

    private static void setupRestClient() {
        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(BASE_URL)
                .build();
        REST_CLIENT = restAdapter.create(ApiInterface.class);
    }
}
```

and in activity i call

```
RestClient.get().getLoginResponse(usernameText, passwordText, clientId, new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
                        @Override
                        public void success(LoginResponse loginResponse, Response response) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), loginResponse.getToken(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

                        }
                    });
```

And in AndroidManifest i set the permission for internet.

Comment: Did you call RestClient.setupRestClient() ??

You should create your RestClient as a Singleton.

Comment: @DinhNhat i am new to android how it is possible?

Comment: set log level  to your builder and check what is the error, upload the logs then new RestAdapter.Builder().setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to make RestClient as a singleton:

```
public class RestClient {

    private static ApiInterface REST_CLIENT;
    private static String BASE_URL = "base_url";

    public RestClient() {}

    public static ApiInterface getInstance() {

       //if REST_CLIENT is null then set-up again. 
        if (REST_CLIENT == null) {
           setupRestClient();
        }
        return REST_CLIENT;
   }

    private static void setupRestClient() {
        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(BASE_URL)
            .build();
        REST_CLIENT = restAdapter.create(ApiInterface.class);
    }
}
```

Then when you wanna call api you should always call:

```
ApiInterface api = RestClient.getInstance();
api.callWhatApiYouWant
```

Comment: Thanks for help but now i got error `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method `

Comment: I have edit answer , please check it. if REST_CLIENT  is null then we have to initialize. Thats way you got NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

I am answering late but it will be useful for others, I preferred to use retrofit 2.

```
// Retrofit
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
// JSON Parsing
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
```

Quit Simple to create instance.

```
public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl) {
   if (retrofit==null) {
     retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build();
  }
 return retrofit;
}
```

Here is Detailed explanation about retrofit 2 android best example and quit simple to understand.
http://al-burraq.com/retrofit-android-get-and-post-api-request-tutorial/