# Retrofit android make error java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I use retrofit android library for rest api call. I implemented RestClient as a singleton class as follows

RestClient.java

```
public class RestClient {

    private static Api REST_CLIENT;
    private static String BASE_URL = "base_url";

    public RestClient() {}

    public static Api getInstance() {
        if (REST_CLIENT != null) {
            setupRestClient();

        }
        return REST_CLIENT;
    }


    private static void setupRestClient() {
        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(BASE_URL)
                .build();
        REST_CLIENT = restAdapter.create(Api.class);
    }
}
```

Then i call api using

```
  Api api = RestClient.getInstance();
    api.getLoginResponse(usernameText, passwordText, android_id, new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
                        @Override
                        public void success(LoginResponse loginResponse, Response response) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), loginResponse.getToken(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

                        }
                    });
```

But when i debug the value of instance `api` is always null and got **java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method error** in logcat

Comment: I believe the if condition is backward in your `getInstance` method: `if (REST_CLIENT != null)` means the code will only run if the `REST_CLIENT` has already been initialized, else, you get back `REST_CLIENT` which is, as we discussed, always `null`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrofit android not working and has no error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32389584/retrofit-android-not-working-and-has-no-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your If condition is wrong in getInstance() method. PLease check it.

```
public class RestClient {

    private static Api REST_CLIENT;
    private static String BASE_URL = "base_url";

    public RestClient() {}

    public static Api getInstance() {
        if (REST_CLIENT == null) {
            setupRestClient();

        }
        return REST_CLIENT;
    }


    private static void setupRestClient() {
        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(BASE_URL)
                .build();
            REST_CLIENT = restAdapter.create(Api.class);
        }
    }
```